# C++ pointer vs dereferenced object

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, dereference

I have the following C++/Qt code:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *itemPointer = this->widget->topLevelItem(0);
QTreeWidgetItem item = *itemPointer;
QTreeWidgetItem *itemPointer2 = &item;

qDebug() << itemPointer->childCount();   // 2 (answer I'm looking for)
qDebug() << (*itemPointer).childCount(); // 2
qDebug() << item.childCount();           // 0
qDebug() << itemPointer2->childCount();  // 0

qDebug() << itemPointer;  // 0xeb6f70
qDebug() << itemPointer2; // 0x7fffeeca7330
```

Shouldn't the dereferenced `item` produce the same results? What changes the pointer?

What is the difference between

```
SomeClass *a = ...;
SomaClass b = *a;
b.x();
```

and

```
SomeClass *a = ...;
(*a).x();
```

?

Comment: You setting the item to the dereference of itemPointer. You are not assigning item to point to the same memory location with item = *itemPointer. If you want them to point to the same location, then item will have to be a pointer with the same address as itemPointer (QTreeWidgetItem *item = itemPointer)

Comment: You have something wrong in copy constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question:

> Shouldn't the dereferenced item produce the same results? What changes the pointer?

Answer:

> It depends on the copy constructor of the class.

When you use:

```
QTreeWidgetItem item = *itemPointer;
```

`item` is constructed by using the copy constructor of `QTreeWidgetItem`, it is not a simple dereferenced object of the pointer. If the copy constructor of `QTreeWidgetItem` doesn't copy the children, `item` will not have any children.

If you want to use just a dereferenced object, you'll have to use a reference object.

```
QTreeWidgetItem& item = *itemPointer;
```

Comment: So there were two things at play here. 1) I tought x = y would mean x equals y instead x equals copy of y. 2) As you said the copy constructor does not give an identical object, which confused me.

Answer (score 2):

Not necessary.

In the first code snippet a new object is created

```
SomeClass *a = ...;
SomaClass b = *a;
b.x();
```

So the result depends on how the copy constructor is defined. For example it can copy only a partial state of the original object.

Comment: So I explicitly need a copy constructor to use this?

Comment: @mLstudent33 Here can be a copy elision. But the copy constructor shall be acceptable.